# JQuery .getJson wont load local file plus how to convert to JavaScript object.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, getjson

Hey guys I am trying to learn how to use JSON files. I understand the basics but I am trying to grasp loading them into an HTML file and I am having a couple of difficulties.

The first difficulty I am having is that if I put in the full file extension to load the file I get an error 'expected hexadecimal digit'. I did some research on it and I think it is because in the file extension it is \u so it is expecting a hexadecimal but I am not sure how to work around it.

The second problem I am having is that if I just use the file extension users.json it works in my editor but not in a browser. It is not loading the file at all, the code is fine (I believe). I think it is just not loading the file because of the file extenion.

Suggestions on how to fix my problems? Thanks in advance.

```
<body>
for output
<div id="forOutput"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 var output;
 $(document).ready(function(){
  alert("JQuery loaded");
 });
 $.getJSON('C:\Users\Spencer\Desktop\JSJqueryTesting\JSONTesting\users.json', function(data) {
  output = data;
for (var i in data.users) {
 alert(data.users[i].firstName + " " + data.users[i].lastName+ " " + data.users[i].joined.month);
    }
});
 $("#forOutput").html("User 1 lastname: " + output.users[1].lastName);
</script>
```

Comment: i believe `$.getJSON` expects a web page URL, not a local file path.

Comment: You really should be doing this kind of stuff on a webserver, not on the local file system. It will work, but you will have to make some security setting changes to make it work on some browsers.

Comment: Ok, I understand that you can only input a URL and I understand why now. Though still if I put both files on my webserver it still wont load the file. I guess i will keep having to work with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The file extension is perfect (.json), however, you can't load local files (because of security reasons). If what you are trying to do, were possible, that would mean any website could access **all** your local files. Now that's really not such a good idea, and therefore (by default) only files that share the same domain(e.g. stackoverflow.com/*) are allowed. This is called [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).